# how to stream HDMI video over IP and receive it via software

Tags: networking, video, hdmi, vga, kvm-switch

### need:

I have a computer connected to a monitor via HDMI @ 1080p (1920x1080).

I need to send the video to remote locations, without breaking the current monitor setup.

Remote locations need to connect via IP and be able to parse the protocol and retrieve the video stream (or screenshots).

### typical solution I use:

I typically use the "Lantronix SpiderDuo" KVM over IP solution which stays in the middle of the video cable and connects to Ethernet. I then connect to its IP address and use their protocol to get the video feed.

Problem is: they only support VGA at maximum resolution of 1600x1200.

### possible solutions:

1. Find a new hardware similar to the [Lantronix SpiderDuo](https://www.lantronix.com/products/lantronix-spiderduo/) that supports HDMI (searched but could not find any..).
2. Split the HDMI signal in 2, then find a new hardware similar to the [Lantronix Spider](https://www.lantronix.com/products/lantronix-spider/) that supports HDMI. Difference from solution 1 is that this hardware doesn't do HDMI passthrough so we need to split it.
3. Split the HDMI signal in 2, then convert one to VGA and **downscale** it, then feed it to the KVM hardware.

### drawing of tentative solution 2

To better understand, here is a drawing of solution 2 above:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is use VLC to capture the screen and then send out a stream to the internet. Then, you can use vlc on other machines to connect to the stream.

More documentation: https://software.grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=14625